# Google Error 403 GetSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

When trying to use getsymbols from quantmod in R im getting the error:

```
Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name,
"&startdate=",  :    cannot open URL
'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:INTC&artdate=Nov+24,+2014&enddate=Mar+21,+2018&output=csv'
In addition: Warning message: In download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=",
Symbols.name, "&startdate=",  :   cannot open URL
'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:INTC&startdate=Nov+24,+2014&enddate=Mar+21,+2018&output=csv':
HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

I'm using the following code

```
myDataUSA<-getSymbols("NASDAQ:INTC",src="google",from='2014-11-24',
                      to='2018-03-21',auto.assign = TRUE)
```

any idea on how to get around this problem?

PS: Tried to search this question but i only saw answers for Yahoo saying its not supported anymore... Also, im not in a VPN or something like that

Comment: Are you able to go to the URL in a browser? When I tried, I see *"We're sorry ... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries."* Sounds to me like they aren't happy with that data being scraped (or it is being scraped incorrectly).

Comment: i get the same error in the browser

Comment: Like many errors, it means what it says. The website is denying you permission to access the file. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Yeah... i wonder if there's any other function i can use or if i should just use another src

Comment: Use a different source. See [quantmod issue #221](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221).